# Set TabPage Header Color

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, header, tabcontrol

Greetings,

I have a tab control and I want to have 1 of the tabs have it's text color changed on a event.
I've found answers like [C# - TabPage Color event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085967/c-tabpage-color-event)
and [C# Winform: How to set the Base Color of a TabControl (not the tabpage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849801/c-winform-how-to-set-the-base-color-of-a-tabcontrol-not-the-tabpage)
but using these sets all colors instead of one.

So I was hoping there is a way to implement this with the tab I wish to change as a method instead of a event?

Something like:

```
public void SetTabPageHeaderColor(TabPage page, Color color) 
{
    //Text Here
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you want to color the tabs, try the following code:

```
this.tabControl1.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
this.tabControl1.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(this.tabControl1_DrawItem);

private Dictionary<TabPage, Color> TabColors = new Dictionary<TabPage, Color>();
private void SetTabHeader(TabPage page, Color color)
{
    TabColors[page] = color;
    tabControl1.Invalidate();
}
private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    //e.DrawBackground();
    using (Brush br = new SolidBrush (TabColors[tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index]]))
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, e.Bounds);
        SizeF sz = e.Graphics.MeasureString(tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Left + (e.Bounds.Width - sz.Width) / 2, e.Bounds.Top + (e.Bounds.Height - sz.Height) / 2 + 1);

        Rectangle rect = e.Bounds;
        rect.Offset(0, 1);
        rect.Inflate(0, -1);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.DarkGray, rect);
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
}
```

Comment: Still based on a event. I want to have a method like "SetTabHeader(TabPage page, Color color)"

Comment: @Levisaxos, I've added the method you required. But you will still require the event.

Comment: Great answer, but it doesn't work that well on Windows 8. Setting the drawing mode to OwnerDrawFixed and adding the drawing event makes the tab tops draw in a much different style from the usual one.

Comment: For tab pages that are not in TabColors, how do we use the default DrawItem?

Comment: is it possible also to cover/color the tab header bottom part white border/area, please check the image here ibb.co/n1F1p57, it's looks odd for that white bottom border on non selected tab headers. THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 22):

For WinForms users reading this - This ONLY works if you set your tab control's DrawMode to OwnerDrawFixed  - the DrawItem event never fires if it's set to Normal.

Answer (score 9):

To add to **Fun Mun Pieng**'s answer which works beautifully on *Horizontal tabs*, if you were to use *Vertical tabs* (like I was) then you would need something like this:

```
    private void tabControl2_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Brush br = new SolidBrush(tabColorDictionary[tabControl2.TabPages[e.Index]]))
        {
            // Color the Tab Header
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, e.Bounds);
            // swap our height and width dimensions
            var rotatedRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, e.Bounds.Height, e.Bounds.Width);

            // Rotate
            e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
            e.Graphics.RotateTransform(-90);

            // Translate to move the rectangle to the correct position.
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Bottom, System.Drawing.Drawing2D.MatrixOrder.Append);

            // Format String
            var drawFormat = new System.Drawing.StringFormat();
            drawFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            drawFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

            // Draw Header Text
            e.Graphics.DrawString(tabControl2.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font, Brushes.Black, rotatedRectangle, drawFormat);
        }
    }
```

I will echo the point that **ROJO1969** made, if this is in WinForms - then you must set DrawMode to **OwnerDrawFixed**.

Special thanks goes out to this wonderful [blog entry](http://blog.csharphelper.com/2012/04/05/easily-draw-rotated-text-on-a-form-in-c.aspx) which described how to do a rotation of text on a form.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       ...    
                
       this.tabControl1.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
       this.tabControl1.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(this.tabControl1_DrawItem);
       ...
}


private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
     try
     {   
          // Draw the background of the control for each item.
          //e.DrawBackground();
            
          if (e.Index == this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex)
          {
              Brush _BackBrush = new SolidBrush(tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].BackColor);
                   

              Rectangle rect = e.Bounds;
              e.Graphics.FillRectangle(_BackBrush, (rect.X) + 4, rect.Y, (rect.Width) - 4, rect.Height);
                    
              SizeF sz = e.Graphics.MeasureString(tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font);
              e.Graphics.DrawString(tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font, Brushes.Black,
                         e.Bounds.Left + (e.Bounds.Width - sz.Width) / 2,
                         e.Bounds.Top + (e.Bounds.Height - sz.Height) / 2 + 1);

         }
         else
         {   
              // 파스톤계 배경색 없앨려면 FromArgb 를 없애면 된다.
              Brush _BackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].BackColor));

              Rectangle rect = e.Bounds;
              e.Graphics.FillRectangle(_BackBrush, rect.X, (rect.Y)-0, rect.Width, (rect.Height)+6);

              SizeF sz = e.Graphics.MeasureString(tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font);
              e.Graphics.DrawString(tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font, Brushes.Black, 
              e.Bounds.Left + (e.Bounds.Width - sz.Width) / 2,
                        e.Bounds.Top + 5);
                    
         }
            
     }
     catch (Exception Ex)
     {
          MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message, "Error Occured", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If any one need to put color for tab header use try this.  My tab name tabControl

```
tabControl.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
tabControl.DrawItem += tabControl1_DrawItem;
```

declear this under main class
then,

```
 private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
            {
                e.DrawBackground();
                Color tabTextColor = Color.FromArgb(0x000001);
                var color = Color.FromArgb(tabTextColor.R, tabTextColor.G, tabTextColor.B); 
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, tabControl.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font, e.Bounds, color);
            }
```

declare this function it will generate output

[final out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRRFE.png)

Comment: Where does the blue background come from for this code?

Comment: The blue color will come to the background of the focused tab.  It is the predefined behavior of TextRenderer.DrawText

Comment: But why did you copy-paste my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41446412/5114784)? Ok, after all you replaced the color part, creating an almost black color from an almost transparent one...

Comment: @MX313: It comes from `e.DrawBackground`, which respects the [`State`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.drawitemstate) of the item to be drawn. @SamyNathan says that is comes from `TextRenderer.DrawText` but it does not paint any background. Btw. if visual styles are enabled the background is drawn differently when `OwnerDrawFixed` is not set but you can customize it if you omit `e.DrawBackground()` and draw the background yourself as the other answers here suggest.

Answer (score 0):

An elaboration of samy's answer... if you need a single tab highlighted a different color, such as pink for an alert tab, then the others to function normally but still highlighted for focus i added as follows:

```
private void tabControlMain_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Index == iTabIndexDiffColor)
            {
                Color cColor =  Color.LightPink;
                using (Brush br = new SolidBrush(cColor))
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, e.Bounds);
                    SizeF sz = e.Graphics.MeasureString(tabControlMain.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tabControlMain.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Left + (e.Bounds.Width - sz.Width) / 2, e.Bounds.Top + (e.Bounds.Height - sz.Height) / 2 + 1);

                    Rectangle rect = e.Bounds;
                    rect.Offset(0, 1);
                    rect.Inflate(0, -1);
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.DarkGray, rect);
                    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                e.DrawBackground();
                Color color; Color tabTextColor;
                if (e.Index == tabControlMain.SelectedIndex)
                    color = Color.White;
                else
                {
                    tabTextColor = Color.FromArgb(0x000001);
                    color = Color.FromArgb(tabTextColor.R, tabTextColor.G, tabTextColor.B);
                }
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, tabControlMain.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font, e.Bounds, color);
            }
        }`
```