# How change autohide area color

Tags: c#, dockpanel-suite

I have a winform application which has 2012 light theme on weifenluo.winformsui.docking.

Problem is that the 2012 light theme is not quite viewable as everything is in light colors. I want to change background color of the docking area: I have changed the document background color but unable to change auto hide area when the windows are hidden.

[image: Screenshot of winform application]

I got properties in weifenluo dockpanel to change the color but its working only 2003 and 2005 theme not in 2012 light theme

public class VS2012LightTheme : ThemeBase

skin.AutoHideStripSkin.DockStripGradient.StartColor = specialBlue; skin.AutoHideStripSkin.DockStripGradient.EndColor = SystemColors.ControlLight;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The areas are controlled by `VS2012LightAutoHideStrip`.

Thus, if you want to change their look and feel, change the controls (start from OnPaint event handler), or write your own.

`ITheme` derived classes only control a small portion of the whole look and feel, so your changes to `VS2012LightTheme` won't achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks bro i found on OnPaint event of VS2012LightAutoHideStrip class

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Tabname.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.X
```

where `X` is the colour you want.

**Refer this link for more info:**
[dockpanel suite](http://robertsmyth.blogspot.in/2008/06/programmatic-pane-nesting-using.html)

Comment: Your screeshots and markings are little confusing.Anyway check the link shared below,it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338587/set-tabpage-header-color  If you find my answer as helpful don't forget to mark this as an answer:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: i am using weifenluo.winformsui.docking

Comment: I have updated my answer with the link for your reference.Check it.It will help you.

Comment: updated images hope these will clear confusions http://postimg.org/image/rmy1zqpyh/ http://postimg.org/image/zeduvm93j/

Comment: Again he changing background color of tab area i want to change autohide area when windows are hide