# Change Specific Tab Page Tab Color / Losing formatting when selecting DrawMode=OwnerDrawFixed

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, controls

While trying to change the color of the tab based on button click event I came across this page:

[Set TabPage Header Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338587/set-tabpage-header-color)

It appears to work, however I lost all the other formatting of my tabs and they now appear blank after I set the DrawMode=OwnerDrawFixed.   How do I set the color of the tab of a specific page and still show the tabs as normal?

Code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.TabControlMain.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(this.TabControlMain_DrawItem);
    SetTabHeader (tabDownload, System.Drawing.Color.Green);
}
private Dictionary<TabPage, Color> TabColors = new Dictionary<TabPage, Color>();
private void SetTabHeader(TabPage page, Color color)
{
    TabColors[page] = color;
    tabDownload.Invalidate();
}

private void TabControlMain_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    //e.DrawBackground();
    using (Brush br = new SolidBrush(TabColors[TabControlMain.TabPages[e.Index]]))
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, e.Bounds);
        SizeF sz = e.Graphics.MeasureString(TabControlMain.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(TabControlMain.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Left + (e.Bounds.Width - sz.Width) / 2, e.Bounds.Top + (e.Bounds.Height - sz.Height) / 2 + 1);

        Rectangle rect = e.Bounds;
        rect.Offset(0, 1);
        rect.Inflate(0, -1);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.DarkGray, rect);
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
}
```

Below is a screenshot[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Y(et)A(nother)TabControl](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12538/Y-et-A-nother-TabControl-A-Custom-Tab-Control-With)

Gives you the possibly to draw own custom headers:

[image: TabControl]

[image: TabControl]

```
public override void DrawTab( Color foreColor,
                              Color backColor,
                              Color highlightColor,
                              Color shadowColor,
                              Color borderColor,
                              bool active,
                              bool mouseOver,
                              DockStyle dock,
                              Graphics graphics,
                              SizeF tabSize )
{
  if( active )
  {
    Pen p = new Pen( borderColor );
    graphics.DrawRectangle( p, 0, 0, tabSize.Width, tabSize.Height );
    p.Dispose();
  }
  else
  {
    Brush b = Brushes.Peru;
    float dif = tabSize.Height / 4.0f;
    RectangleF r = new RectangleF( 0.0f, dif, 
         tabSize.Width, tabSize.Height - dif - dif );
    graphics.FillRectangle( b, r );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In principle your code works, if not fine then at least sufficiently.

But you need to fix a few simple issues:

- Of course, if your Tab is `OwnerDrawn` you need to do it from the start, not just after pressing the Button! So hook up the event right from the start, best in the `Property-Event Tab` so that it is placed in the `Desgner.cs` file where it belongs.

Now the `Tabs` are drawn and their Label texts show.

- If you want to change a color you need to Invalidate the `Tab` Control, **not** the `TabPage`!

so change

```
tabDownload.Invalidate();
```

to

```
TabControlMain.Invalidate();
```

To make the example complete I have done only this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TabPage tp in TabControlMain.TabPages)
            TabColors.Add(tp, tp.BackColor);
}
```

This sets all `Tab` colors in the Dictionary to the Colors of the `Pages`.

- The code to draw the `FocusRectangle` could be improved.

First set the `Padding` like this:

```
this.TabControlMain.Padding = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 4);
```

This gives us enough room to draw a nice `FocusRectangle`..

Then change the code to draw it only on the selected Tab, maybe like this:

```
    if (TabControlMain.SelectedIndex == e.Index)
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Gray))
        {
            pen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot;
            Rectangle rect = e.Bounds;
            rect.Offset(0, 1);
            rect.Inflate(-3,-2);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
        }
```

Now it looks like this:

[image]

Of course managing the colors is up to you..