# how to set backcolor for tabcontrol in windows application

Tags: c#, windows

I created tab control in windows application. for background color I gave following code `tabPage_from.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(230, 247, 254);`

in this color set for tab page only. How I set back color for tab header?

Comment: For tab header or tab page?

Comment: There's something you are missing. The code will work if everything is fine

Comment: i want to add color for tab header

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom tab control. [This is](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91387/Painting-Your-Own-Tabs-Second-Edition) a good sample to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following links.

[Set TabPage Header Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338587/set-tabpage-header-color)

http://dotnetrix.co.uk/tabcontrol.htm