# visual C# Change tab header colour

Tags: c#, colors, tabs, tabcontrol

I followed this solution [set-tabpage-header-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338587/set-tabpage-header-color/5338631#5338631) to change the colours on the title of my tabs. However, this sets the same colour on the tab headers of all the tabs in the tabcontrol. Can you help me change the colour only on the header of the selected tab ?
really appreciate any help here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DrawItemEventArgs e` parameter will tell you all you need.

To draw ther headers in **various** colors replace  `Brushes.Black` by `myBrush` and put the `DrawString` in a using clause like this:

```
using (SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush (tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].ForeColor))
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font, myBrush ,
                          e.Bounds.Left + (e.Bounds.Width - sz.Width) / 2, 
                          e.Bounds.Top + (e.Bounds.Height - sz.Height) / 2 + 1);
}
```

Now each header will be drawn in the `ForeColor` of its `TabPage`.

Replacing the `DrawString` by a [`TextRenderer.DrawText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext(v=vs.110).aspx) would be even better!

If you only want to change the color of the **selected** tab simply use a check like this:

```
SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush (e.State.HasFlag(DrawItemState.Selected) ? 
                     SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText : SystemColors.ControlText)
```

Comment: thanks! I realised that the method is called for every tab in the tabcontrol. I thought it was only called for the selected tab. now it makes sense. thanks a lot